# Forms.label won't show numbers?

Tags: c#, forms, label

I'm trying to output a message through a label in Forms. I do it by doing like this:

```
uint myUint = 50;

myLabel.Text = "Cost: " + myUint.ToString();
```

All I get is this:

[image]

I've done things like this countless times before without any issues. Does any of you know why this happens?

Comment: Accidentally set `AutoSize` of `myLabel` set to `false`?

Comment: Your code works on my pc, perhaps something is overlapping the "50"

Comment: Agree with @Koen your code is working perfectly fine on my pc too.

Comment: Check the `AutoSize` property of the `lable`. It should be set to `true` if you want `lable` to grow as big as the text.

Comment: Either that or make it large enough..